# Is there an easy way to interact with web pages within a C program running on an FPGA?

Tags: c, embedded, fpga, nios

First of all: I'm an electronic engineer, so I'm not really comfortable with high-level coding, I barely "speak" C. For a class project I need to develop an embedded application on an Altera FPGA using a NiosII softcore processor. We wanted to try reading some data from the Internet and then do something with it (i.e. displaying it in some way), but we have no idea how to do that without having to learn a load of new things, and without running an OS. Is there an easy way to do this? I read about cURL but my understanding is it needs an OS. What other options do we have? Literally any data easy enough to access is okay, we'll try to be creative with it.

What I know is that we have a Wifi module that should take care of the TCP/IP protocol, exchanging data to the FPGA through UART.

I'm sorry this may sound like a not very informed question, but I need to understand if this project is feasable before undertaking it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Part will depend on what you can do with that wifi module, but the essentials would be:
- open a tcp/ip socket,
 
- connect to an http server on port 80, using that socket
- write `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n` to the socket, the / is the path to the object like `/sensor/temperature`
- read the response from the socket

A typical response would be something like:

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2019 14:31:05 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
    Last-Modified: Mon, 20 Jul 2009 04:29:15 GMT
    ETag: "1fdbfa-2d-46f1b949d9cc0"
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Content-Length: 45
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html

    <html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

Comment: What kind of data would I be able to download this way? any web page, or is there some kind of limit? Sorry, my knowledge in this field is very restricted. I'm gonna attend some lectures on the subject in a few weeks, but then it'll too late to decide on this project. Kudos to you!

Comment: Pretty much any kind of data.  Things that would be tougher would be https sites (ssl/tls) since you'd have to then have crypto libraries, though maybe that wifi module would have some built-in crypto.  Parsing complex sites would also be outside the scope of what you'd want to do in that FPGA.  If you wanted to skip http and had a known endpoint that supported your own protocol  you could make your parsing a lot easier.  For example you had a program that would send temperature readings every N seconds to anyone connected.  You'd just need to connect and it would auto send you data.

Comment: Are APIs a viable option? It seems like a lot of websites offer those, but I'm not sure whether they need an OS or not

Comment: Depends on the API, they might require a user-agent or other HTTP headers, it increases the complexity of what you send.  To add headers, instead of doing the `\r\n\r\n` do a single `\r\n` between headers and do the `\r\n\r\n` at the end of them.  Easiest way to find what it requires, fire up a packet sniffer (like wireshark) and hit the api in question with curl and you can just copy what curl sent.